# Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched

Tags: c#, lambda, concurrency

I have a concurrent Dictionary in C#:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, dynamic> cache =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, dynamic>();
```

I'm trying to add or update a dynamic value to the dictionary

```
public void SetCache(string key, dynamic value)
{
       cache.AddOrUpdate(key, value, (k, v) => value);
}
```

but I get the following error. What is the problem with the code? [Example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/COit8I).

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a
>   dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a
>   delegate or expression tree type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear I think.

An anonymous lambda can represent a delegate (and there can be many matching delegate types) or an expression tree. It does not have a type by itself until assigned to a variable of specific type or, used in a context where a specific type is expected. When regular (non-dynamic) types are used the compiler can usually deduce target type (such as `Func<string, string>`). When dynamic types are involved though - compiler cannot do that, because all resolutions are now performed at runtime, not at compile time. So compiler will not assign type `Func<string, dynamic, dynamic>` to your lambda and you should do it yourself (as compiler suggests):

```
cache.AddOrUpdate(key, value, (Func<string, dynamic, dynamic>) ((k, v) => value));
```

[Example here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CymnPc)

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic just bypasses static type checking. However you are trying to use it as a code pointer, and as the error says, you need to cast it to a delegate or expression tree. The static type checking is not bypassed in this circumstance.